# How to ensure (like a try-finally) destruction of a HEAP-ALLOCATED object

Tags: c++, heap-memory, raii, try-finally

I'm looking for a way to ensure that an object that is executed on the heap is ALWAYS deallocated when I'm done with it.

I know that if it's allocated on the stack, I can use RAII to ensure it will be taken care of - unfortunately, this won't work for me (at least directly) because the object in question is actually created by calling an api function, which then returns a pointer to the object it creates on the heap.

So, conceptually, what I want to do is something like:

```
TheApi::ApiObject* p_myObj = TheApi::createAnApiObj();
try
{
    doStuffWithMyObjThatMayError(p_myObj);
}
finally
{
    delete p_myObj;
}
```

The only thing I can think of to do would be to make some sort of dummy cleanup class, and create an instance of that on the stack:

```
class MegaMaid
{
private:
    TheApi::ApiObject* toFree;
public:
    MegaMaid(TheApi::ApiObject* toFree)
    {
        this->toFree = toFree;
    }

    ~MegaMaid()
    {
        delete toFree;
    }
};

void doStuff()
{
    TheApi::ApiObject* p_myObj = TheApi::createAnApiObj();
    TheApi::ApiObject* p_myObj;
    MegaMaid cleaner(p_myObj);
    doStuffWithMyObjThatMayError(p_myObj);
}
```

Is there a better way to accomplish this? Or is this the accepted solution?

Comment: And you cannot fix the (broken) API?

Comment: If an API function returns a pointer, are you 110% certain that you can call `delete` on that pointer? Does the API say that? Or does it provide its own cleanup function?

Comment: Nemo - nope, I'm stuck with the API as it is. =P

Comment: Kerrek - yeah, I'm positive. they do exactly that in some sample code they provide...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can still use RAII on pointers returned by functions. You can use smart pointers (which is exactly what the dummy class you are describing is) like this:

```
std::unique_ptr<TheApi::ApiObject> p_myObj(TheApi::createAnApiObj());
```

Comment: Hmm, thanks... that seems exactly like what I was looking for!

Comment: So I may have spoken a little hastily... in my particular case, you're actually supposed to call a close method on ApiObject, AND delete it... I know, poor design on the api side, this should be handled in the destructor for ApiObject... what's the standard way for handling this situation?

Comment: @PaulMolodowitch Use a custom deleter. `std::unique_ptr<T>` actually is `std::unique_ptr<T, std::default_delete<T>>` where `std::default_delete<T>::operator()(T* p);` does `delete p;`. You can use a `std::unique_ptr<T, place_custom_deleter_here>` to do what you want come destruction time.

Answer (score 6):

That "dummy class" is known as "smart pointer". You should check out `std::auto_ptr` or `boost::shared_ptr`. They provide exactly what you look for.